# SVG Element attribute xmlns

Tags: html, css, svg, reference

what does HTML5  SVG  attribute "xmlns" means , I am pointing  to  svg example here  http://www.tutorialspark.com/html5/HTML5_SVG_Apps.php?

Answer (score 0):

It stands for XML Namespace.

From the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/):

> We envision applications of Extensible Markup Language (XML) where a single XML document may contain elements and attributes (here referred to as a "markup vocabulary") that are defined for and used by multiple software modules.... Document constructs should have names constructed so as to avoid clashes between names from different markup vocabularies